# Change bitmap pixels according to byteBuffer

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, bytebuffer

I'm trying to clear unwanted area from picture, in the most efficient way,

My code for now:

```
Bitmap picture = ...;
ByteBuffer mask = ...;
int height = picture.getHeight();
int width = picture.getWidth();
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        float currFloat = mask.getFloat();
        if (currFloat > 0.7) {
            req.setPixel(x, y, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }
}
```

My mask (ByteBuffer of (for example) 8*8):

[image: mask]

My picture (Bitmap of 8*8):

[image]

Excepted result:

[image]

Thankfully, it works,
but unfortunately it takes too long since there are a lot of images to process..

There is any way to make it work faster? (something like matrix multiplication?)

I can transform the bitmap into buffer using

```
picture.copyPixelsToBuffer(buff)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider using JNI and doing the work in C/C++, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398670/rotating-a-bitmap-using-jni-ndk for example

Comment: C and JNI are your best answers, but even just avoiding setPixel and using getPixels() to get an array of pixels and modifying that directly would be a big speedup.

Comment: I do not understand that you would put floats in a ByteBuffer.